# HTTP Routing in Symfony

Tags: php, laravel, symfony

I've been developing a lot of my projects in the Laravel Framework for quite a while now, but not I'm working for a company who uses Symfony instead of Laravel.

On my way adapting to Symfony I got confused with the HTTP routing.

In Laravel you specify the HTTP method and link it to a route, like so:

```
Route::get('/', 'PageController@index');
Route::post('/', 'PageController@contact');
```

If you send a get request to '/' it will call the index method in PageController. If you send a post request it will call the contact method in PageController.

Now in Symfony I don't know how to do proper HTTP routing. I've seen people handle both get and post request in one method. For example:

```
public function index()
{
     if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
        // handle post request and return something
     }

     // return something else
}
```

What I did, which looks a lot like the Laravel way is specifying 2 separate methods to handle each request:

```
/**
 * @Route("/", name="homepage")
 * @Method("GET")
 */
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
    // return the index page
}

/**
 * @Route("/", name="contact")
 * @Method("POST")
 */
public function contactAction()
{
    // handle post request and return something
}
```

To summarize my question(s):

1. **How to handle post requests in Symfony?**
2. **What are the best-practises to handle those requests?**
3. **What are naming conventions for such methods (indexPost/indexGet, indexAction/contactAction)?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This might help: http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/index.html In my experience it's best to understand a framework on it's own terms before trying to do things that the way you are used to doing things.  And out of the box, Symfony controller methods generally end in Action.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've already read most of the Symfony documentation, and I couldn't find anything specific about handling posts.

Comment: The docs show the Symfony way to handle posted forms: http://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#handling-form-submissions Seems like you actually copied this into to your question.  There are some folks who say that get/post should be handled by separate actions.  But, like it or not, the Symfony approach is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to go through each of your questions,

**How to handle post requests in Symfony**

Example with YML routes

```
my_route_post:
    path:     /route/path
    defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Foo:edit }
    methods:  [POST]
my_route_get:
    path:     /route/path
    defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Foo:show }
    methods:  [GET]
```

And you can define the controller actions :

```
class FooController extends Controller {

    public function editAction(Request $request)
    {
        // POST request here
    }

    public function showAction()
    {
        // GET request here
    }
}
```

**What are the best-practises to handle those requests**

I think both practises of creating a controller action to handle each HTTP request types or handling a POST request in the same method as GET are fine. Depending on which one fits your needs the best.

**What are naming conventions for such methods (indexPost/indexGet, indexAction/contactAction)?**

> Each action method in a controller class is suffixed with Action
>   (again, this isn't required, but some shortcuts rely on this).

From : https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller.html

Comment: Is YAML the way most Symfony developers go? Or do they use annotations as I did in my example? Is it personal preference?

Comment: I don't know if any of those can give you performance gain, i know that YAML, XML, and Annotations are popular, i think it is mostly personnal preference. (I usually do it with YAML because it's very clear imo)